# How to browse over a page using PhantomJS and Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, phantomjs

I got some DIV elements on a web page. Totally there are abound 30 DIV blocks of the following similar structure:

```html
<div class="w-dyn-item">  
<a href="/project/soft" class="jobs-wrapper no-line w-inline-block w-clearfix">
<div class="jobs-client">
<img data-qazy="true" src="https://global.com/test.jpg" alt="Soft" class="image-9">
<div style="background-color:#cd7f32" class="job-time">Level 1</div>
</div>
<div class="jobs-content w-clearfix">
<div class="w-clearfix">
<div class="text-block-19 w-condition-invisible">PROMO</div>
<h3 class="job-title">Soft</h3>
<img height="30" data-qazy="true" src="https://global.com/test.jpg" alt="Soft" class="image-15 w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small"></div>
<div class="div-block w-clearfix">
<div class="text-block-4">Italy</div>
<div class="text-block-4 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny">AMB</div>
<div class="text-block-4 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny">GTL</div>
<div class="text-block-13">January 10, 2017</div><div class="text-block-14">End date:</div></div><div class="space small"></div><p class="paragraph-3">Text text text</p></div>   
</a> 
</div>
```

I am trying to access `a href` and click on the link. However, the problem is that I cannot use `find_element_by_link_text`, because the link text does not exist. Is it possible to access `a href` by class `class="jobs-wrapper no-line w-inline-block w-clearfix"`? When I used `find_element_by_class_name`, I got the error `Message: {"errorMessage":"Compound class names not permitted","request`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://myurl.com/")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("//a href").click()
print driver.current_url
driver.quit()
```

Comment: you want to click the `a` tag? that's it?

Comment: @OmarEinea: Yes. This is the first day I am using Selenium and PhantomJS. Sorry, if the question is very simple.

Comment: If this is an internal website, add (or make somebody add) new IDs or classes, e.g. `qa-project-link`. Selecting by arbitrary CSS classes will break as soon as somebody edits the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is because Selenium's `find_element_by_class_name` does not support multiple classes.
Use a CSS selector with `find_elements_by_css_selector` instead:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.jobs-wrapper.no-line.w-inline-block.w-clearfix')
```

Will select all tags with your wanted class, then you can iterate over them and use `click()` or any other wanted action

**EDIT**

Following your comment, new snippet to help you do what you want:

```
result = {}
urls = []
# 'elements' is a the list you previously obtained using the css selector
for element in elements:
    urls.append(element.get_attribute('href'))


# Now you can iterate over all extracted hrefs:
for url in urls:
    url_data = {}
    driver.get(url)
    field1 = driver.find_element_by_id('wanted_id_1')
    url_data['field1'] = field1
    field2 = driver.find_element_by_id('wanted_id_2')
    url_data['field2'] = field2
    result[url] = url_data
```

Now, `result` is a dictionary in a structure similar to what you wanted.

Note that `field1` and `field2` are of type `WebElement` so you'll probably need to do something with them first (extract attribute, text, etc).

Also, on personal note, Look into the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) together with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), they might be a way better fit than `Selenium` for this or future similar cases.

Comment: Thanks. I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`.

Comment: @Markus that's because your query returns a list of elements. It might be a list with one element, but it's still a list. You need to check whether it's bigger than 0 and click on the first element.

Comment: That's because you're getting a list of elements, which you can't perform a click on. You need to **iterate** over the list (i.e `for element in mylist: element.click()`

Comment: @EvyatarMeged: Yes, the list contains multiple links. That's true. But when I iterate over them as you shown, I get this error `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache"`.

Comment: @Markus Hmm, I think that's because after clicking on one of the hrefs, your `driver` simply moves to another URL, making all other hrefs unclickable as they do not exist in that URL. I don't recommend opening a new webdriver for each URL though. What is your final goal here ? what are you trying to accomplish ? try elaborating and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged: I want to collect all URL's from `a href`. Then I want to open each of these URL's and collect some data using `find_element_by_id`. The structure of all pages of these URL's is the same. My final goal is to have a data structure like this `[url1 : {"field1": 123, "field2": 456}, url1 : {"field1": 123, "field2": 456}, ... ]`

Answer (score 2):

If your only requirement is to click the `a` tag inside a tag with `w-dyn-item` class, then you could do it like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("w-dyn-item").find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
```

To iterate over all tags with `w-dyn-item` class -> click the `a` inside them -> do something -> go back, do this:

```
tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item")
for i in range(len(tags)):
    tag = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item")[i]
    tag.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
    # Do what you want inside the page...
    driver.back()
```

The key here is of course to go back to the root page after you're done with the inner page.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it. I think that it gets some first `a` from the header of a web page. But I have a container with `div` elements of the class `w-dyn-item`. I need to click on `a` inside each of these `div` elements.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! But it takes only the first `div`. Do you know how to iterate over all `div` of the class `w-dyn-item`?

Comment: I get this error `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"116","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:47807","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"tag name\", \"sessionId\": \"b2ddb140-f92c-11e7-86cf-2bfda6dce865\", \"id\": \":wdc:1515935604720\", \"value\": \"a\"}"`

Comment: it returns that after it clicks the first link?

Comment: It was returning just the first URL. I changed it as follows: `num_options = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item"))
for i in range(num_options):
    tag = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item")[i]
    tag.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
    print driver.current_url`. Now it returns around 6 URLs and then it says `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: do you need to click and load the link or you only want to get all links?

Comment: No, I need to click and load. Then, after loading, I will process each new page, collect data, and go back to the initial list, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

To access and click the `a href` you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='w-dyn-item']/a[@href='/project/soft']").click()
```